# React TypeError: Cannot read property 'categoryName' of undefined problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to get my categoryName from initialState but it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'categoryName' of undefined problem". How can I solve this case?
here is my initialState.js file:

```
export default {
  currentCategory:{categoryName:"Beverages"},
  categories:[]
};
```

And here is my categoryList.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
import * as categoryActions from '../../redux/actions/categoryActions'


class CategoryList extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.actions.getCategories()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Categories {this.props.categories.legnth}</h3>
        <h5>Seçili Kategori: {this.props.currentCategory.categoryName}</h5>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    currentCategory: state.changeCategoryReducers,
    categories:state.categoryListReducer
  }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return {
    actions:{
      getCategories:bindActionCreators(categoryActions.getCategories,dispatch)
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(CategoryList);
```

I am using reducers , redux and thunk but I have a problem I think should be install problem. But I cant solve which package is missed. For any advice will be very effective.
And here is my changeCategoryReducer.js:

```
import * as actionTypes from "../actions/actionTypes";
import initialState from "./initialState";

export default function changeCategoryReducer(
  state = initialState.currentCategory,
  action
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.CHANGE_CATEGORY:
      return action.payload;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

here is my index.js file:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import changeCategoryReducer from "./changeCategoryReducer";
import categoryListReducer from './categoryListReducer';


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  changeCategoryReducer,
  categoryListReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: If you are fetching categories in `componentDidMount` then categories will be undefined on the first render.

Comment: How can I solve this?

Comment: conditionally render the component on the first render, `return() {<div>{categories.length > 0 ? <h3>Categories {this.props.categories.categoryName}</h3> : <h3>Loading...</h3> }</div>}`

Comment: I added this ```<div>
        {this.props.categories.length > 0 ? <h3>Categories {this.props.categories.legnth}</h3> : <h3>Loading...</h3> }
        {this.props.currentCategory.categoryName > 0 ? <h3>Categories {this.props.currentCategory.categoryName}</h3> : <h3>Loading...</h3> }
      </div>``` but still it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'categoryName' of undefined"

Comment: Not sure then, (also you have mistyped `legnth`)

Comment: Thank you for trying. I will correct the spelling mistake. Have a nice day.

Comment: Probably in your mapStateToProps you are mapping state.changeCategoryReducers instead of state.changeCategoryReducer. There is an extra (s). Typo

Comment: @Tauseef Ahmad You are perfect! I have no idea how you see it. But I'm so grateful to you. You saved my day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see this line: `currentCategory: state.changeCategoryReducers,`
But @Tauseef Ahmad saw.
It should be like this: `currentCategory: state.changeCategoryReducer,`